# Menu Transition/Animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css-transitions

Okay so I have this idea for a menu but I really have no idea how to implement it or what is required, I am very new to web design. So basically when an item on the menu is highlighted I want the slider bar to move under the highlighted item like so

http://s7.postimage.org/qa3vfh797/purple.gif

So when I am on a page I want the slider under the menu tab that relates to the page. When I hover over an item in the menu the slider slides from the current tab to the highlighted one. When the user un-highlights it, it returns to the tab that relates to the page the user is on. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have a few options. I would recommend getting to know JavaScript. In particular learning jQuery and looking at just a few choices you have there http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to provide you with a jsfiddle example but no need to reinvent the wheel.

jQuery MagicLine:
[Article](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/) & [Demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/)

If this is not the direction you would like to go in, then I suggest using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), in particular, the tabs section: [here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover). Make sure to use jQueryUI with [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), which allows for user customization.

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the complete code, but I'll point you in the right direction with some keywords to search for.
What you need is to create a  for the bar that will slide underneath your menu items.
Encapsulate each menu item within a div and implement a onMouseOver event for each of them.
Then in onMouseOver event, you need to move the div from its current location to under this menu div, i.e. change slider div's offsetLeft to the offsetLeft value for the menu div (if you use jquery, it provides handy functions to get this).
Now changing the div's position will directly move it there. If you want to have it done in a 'slide' animation, then you need to move it in steps, let's say in increments of 5 px each time. For this use setTimeOut function. Create a function to change slider div's offsetLeft value in 5 px increments, and call this function again and again till it reaches its destination via setTimeout function. setTimeout basically is a timer, that will call a function after specified amount of time.

This should give you enough to search on google :)

Comment: Appreciate the help! I had my div tag moving a set amount when it rolled over the menu items I just need to set it to the x position of my menuItem div, but Dom has given me exactly what I need but I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yeah, I saw Dom's comment, and I think that's exactly what you need. I was just trying to explain it if you have to build without using any libraries :).